# Install pybrain on python 3.2

Tags: python-3.x, pybrain

I'm trying to install pybrain on python 3.2. It says here: https://github.com/pybrain/pybrain/pull/85 that it should work. However it does not for me.

I tried:

$export PYTHONPATH=$PYTHONPATH:'/home/luis/Documents/pybrain/'https://github.com/pybrain/pybrain/pull/85

which works well for python 2.7.

Did somebody get it to work?

Answer (score 8):

After hours of "what the hell?!"s I installed it.
First the installer suggested is not updated for Python3 so I installed Distribute. With that installed I was able to use `python setup.py install` in the directory where I unrared pybrain. It gave a ton of errors. So I found [this article](http://habrahabr.ru/post/148597/) (god bless google translate) and used 2to3 on pybrain directory. After I tried to install it again it gave an error on `from string import split` so I edited the file and removed that line (it is not needed really) and tried yet another time. This time no errors occurred and I was able to import pybrain without any problems. The same problem with the `from string import split` occurs in utilities.py again, so edit that line too.

I used 2to3 to turn examples to python3 too. benchmarkplots.py seems to work.

Answer (score 7):

Update:
pybrain now supports python3 
Here's how to install if you run into trouble

pip install https://github.com/pybrain/pybrain/archive/0.3.3.zip

Or just grab latest github pybrain release.

Comment: I'm not sure what's wrong with icoz PyBrain port but for me it doesn't work at all. When training, error increases rather than decrease. I tried exact same code (copy-paste and fix compatibility issues) with python2 version and it worked as expected. Use with caution.